# Finding the present id of table in database using php

Tags: php, upload

I'm creating form for multiple photos to be uploaded and i want create a directory which is named as the id of the table, the id should be the present id in which the form will be uploaded , in sort i want the current id of the table of database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not that clear, so let me phrase what I think is going on, and correct me where I have misinterpret you.

You have a table that stores information about photos. The table has an ID column with auto_increment set. Whenever you insert something into the database, you want to retreive this ID so you can create a folder to store your photos in. Correct?

Basically, execute your query, which would be something like:

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` SET `name`="Name of photo", `filename`="photo.png"
```

then do the following:

```
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

or if you are using mysqli:

```
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id();
```

With this `$last_id` you can now make a folder etc...

Comment: but sorry i didn't understood your answer

Comment: you basically retreive the last id with the php command `mysql_insert_id();` Whatever variable you assign it to will then have the number of the latest ID, which will only work if there's an ID column with auto_increment set in the table.